# Migrate iCloud local store to iCloud with Magic Record

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

Can anyone please tell me, how to migrate local store to icloud, when using Magic record. Will magic record has any support for that. Is there any documentation for magic Record.
I am struggling from three days.

```
NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ABC.sqlite"];

NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel MR_defaultManagedObjectModel];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coord = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

NSURL *seedStoreURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ABCCloud"];
NSError *seedStoreError;
NSDictionary *seedStoreOptions = @{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption: @YES};

NSPersistentStore *seedStore = [coord addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:seedStoreURL options:seedStoreOptions error:&seedStoreError];

NSDictionary *iCloudOptions =
@{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"CloudStore"};
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;

NSPersistentStore *iCloudStore = [coord migratePersistentStore:seedStore
                                                         toURL:storeURL
                                                       options:iCloudOptions
                                                      withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                         error:&error];
```

Sorry I removed magical record code now. This is the code i write for migration, but persistent store is nil..

This is the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'nil is not a valid persistent
>   store'

Comment: I dont think `Magic Record` has anything to do with this.

Comment: but when i migrates core data, it will give error..

Comment: What error? paste your stacktrace